# How to reload specific widgets in flutter without its parent?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building an app in Flutter,that supposed to be a social network app-similar to faceboook.
[image]
I have implemented a like button-when pressed is sending the server the request,and then depending on the status code it sets the state.My problem begins when the setState() is rendering again the avatar picture,or creating it again from scratch(the avatar is stored in a 64base String).
the likePress is a future that sends the request and then sets the boolean `isLiked` accordingly.
this is the creating of the like button:

```
buildLikeButton(int ownerId, int postId) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
        child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: getLike(ownerId, postId),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              IconButton likeButton;
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                isLiked = snapshot.data;
                likeButton = createLikeButton(ownerId, postId);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                isLiked = false;
                likeButton = createLikeButton(ownerId, postId);
                print('the snapshot has an error ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                isLiked = false;
                likeButton = createLikeButton(ownerId, postId);
              }
              return likeButton;
            }));
  }

createLikeButton(int ownerId, int postId) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: returnLikeIcon(isLiked),
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      onPressed: () async {
        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {
            Future lol = likePress(ownerId, postId).then((onValue) {});
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

and this is the creation of the avatar:

```
createAvatar(BuildContext context, avatar_base64, int ownerId) {
    Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(avatar_base64.split(',').last);

    return RepaintBoundary(
        child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 25.0,
      backgroundImage: MemoryImage(bytes),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ));
  }
```

The widget that displays them together is the `Post` widget which i have created for this project,and this is it's build function:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.2),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              blurRadius: 1.0,
              spreadRadius: 1.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
              offset: Offset(
                5.0, // horizontal, move right 10
                5.0, // vertical, move down 10
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          child: Card(
              elevation: 10.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                      fit: FlexFit.loose,
                      child: postInfo(context, time, ownerId)),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    indent: 10.0,
                    endIndent: 10.0,
                  ),
                  postContent(content),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    indent: 10.0,
                    endIndent: 10.0,
                  ),
                  createButtonBar(ownerId, postId),
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
```

`postInfo` is just a FutureBuilder that builds the ListTile that adds up the avatar and the name, and `createButtonBar` creates the like button and 2 more buttons.

I would like to change the icon when the user presses the like button,but only if the server has responded with the right status code and without rendering and creating the whole `Post` widget over again.Thank you for the trouble!

Comment: Only set state of that particular object which is updated.

Comment: then why does the avatar picture renders itself again?

Comment: I'll suggest to go with a proper implementation whether it is bloc or providers. In this way you can handle states properly

Comment: I am not familiar with your suggestions,will try and read about them,but for now i still would like for this to work without writing everything again.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the avatar is beneath the point where you are calling *setState(() {})*. In your case, the method is probably inside that particular widget and the widget is being rebuilt.

I suggest for you to solve the problem to move the creation of the avatar above. In this way, if you need to rebuild the object the avatar will not be created anew but simply placed within the new widget. Place some *debugPrint*s around to speed up the process and try to refactor the code to see if you missed something.

Comment: apparently the entire build method is ran when setState() is called.is there any way to exclude a widget from being built again?

Comment: No, there is not. As the documentation states the build method is directly called from the framework in some cases, and these include the setState method. You could eventually move part of your app logic to the initState method which is only called once in the entire life of the widget, when it is inserted in the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a better look at my code,I decided to create a different Widget for each part  of the post,so I can initialize everything that will not be built again outside of the `build` method.

---

**so if you want to exclude a widget from the `setState()` method, you need to move it outside the current widget(by creating a widget for it) and just create an instance of it as a parameter in the constructor.**

---

In more detail,I created a class named `PostHeader` and there i created the avatar and the `ListTile` containing it,then i created an instance of it inside the `Post` class,so it is not created inside the `build` method of the `Post` class.